# parallelize list.map for concurrent rdd jobs

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, apache-spark

according to a posting
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spark-users/3QIn42VbQe0

This code will submit all jobs directly to Spark's scheduler, and you get a list of "Future"s back.

```
val rdds: List[RDD[T]] = ...

val futures = rdds.map { rdd =>
  rdd.map(...).reduceByKey(...).collect()
}
```

I am wondering whether adding .par would speed this up, as in
    rdds.par.map

or, maybe the author meant that each map entry would be just a spark job submission, and running them in sequence would be just as fast.

Comment: Did you read through the rest of the thread?

Comment: which part? about future, or about par? I read them. what do you want to tell me?

Comment: The code you posted is incorrect and doesn't return futures.  It does everything sequentially.

Comment: I know it doesn't return futures, and that it does everything sequentially. The author proposed this, I think, because each map step simply submits an rdd job and quickly returns do submit the next one. I am asking if anyone knows this to be true. if the inner rdd.map is synchronous, then Xin is completely wrong on his post. I would wonder about that.

Comment: But the next post right after his informs him that his code is incorrect, to which he agrees.  He meant to wrap everything with `future(...)`.  So when you say "the author proposed this", he actually meant to return futures.  He's not actually proposing what you're saying.

Comment: I think I got it now. The author is using future to make each rdd.map(...).reduceByKey(...).collect() call asynchronous. So future must be added in to make this work.

Comment: Yep, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code provided, the RDDs will be evaluated sequentially.  When you call `.collect` on an RDD, the RDD transformation is evaluated and the results are collected in the driver.  The driver is blocked while the results are collected.

If you were to change it to `rdds.par.map { ... }`, then the `.collect`s would be called in parallel and all RDDs would be evaluated at the same time.  This then leaves it to the Spark scheduling mechanism to decide how to share the cluster between the RDDs.

Comment: That's what I am looking for. And I just reached the same conclusion. The parallelization that the author is talking about comes from using Future.